# Get Page Number from PDF displayed in WKWebView for Bookmarking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, wkwebview

I have implemented WKWebView and displayed a PDF file in it, now I want to bookmark pages. For that I need to know

```
1) How to get current Page Number of PDF displayed
2) How to scroll WKWebView to that page number later on.
```

So far I've done this:

```
          let pathOfPDF = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pdfFile", ofType: "pdf")!)
      let request = URLRequest(url: pathOfPDF)

     pdfView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width/26, y: view.frame.height/12.5, width: view.frame.width-view.frame.width/13, height: view.frame.height - view.frame.height/12.5)

    pdfView.uiDelegate = self
    activityIndicatorIcon.hidesWhenStopped = true
    pdfView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    pdfView.load(request)
    pdfView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Comment: This is not likely to be possible. If all you are displaying is a PDF, you might want to consider using `PDFView` instead.